# Unable to install Elementary OS in Acer Aspire F-15

Tags: system-installation, usb, filesystem

I'm trying to install Elementary OS in an Acer Aspire F-15 laptop using a USB and following the steps that appear in the [official page](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#installation). But after selecting the option of installing Elementary OS or the option of try without installing, the following error appears: `Unable to find a medium containing a live file system usb`

I tested the USB in another computer and Elementary OS works perfectly, so the problem might be in the configuration of my computer. Does anyone know which could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works not using an USB 3.0

Answer (score -1):

Set the BIOS to only use AHCI when booting. Some laptops have are set to work with the RAID controller only.

Comment: I have it in AHCI mode, but still doesn't work, any other suggestion? @Levo75

Comment: Does your BIOS contain any options for enabling or disabling USB drives as boot options? Have you checked for BIOS updates from the Acer website? The update logs may contain clues to bugs pertaining to this issue.